# Как исправить ошибки скопированного стиля?

Tags: css

Скопировал стили таблиц.

Стили рабочие, но применились не полностью, применились частично.

При том, та часть, которая не применилась выделяется VS Code как такая, что с ошибками.

Участок кода, который не работает:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

table {
    width: 800px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

th,
td {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #fff;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
}

thead {
    th {
        background-color: #55608f;
    }
}

tbody {
    tr {
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        }
    }
    td {
        position: relative;
        &:hover {
            &:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: -9999px;
                bottom: -9999px;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                z-index: -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот, что не нравится VS Code:

[image: Ошибки из ВС код]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Это SASS (синтаксис SCSS), код надо откомпилировать в CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
table {
  width: 800px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
thead th {
  background-color: #55608f;
}
tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
tbody td {
  position: relative;
}
tbody td:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Онлайн конвертер SCSS=>CSS](https://cssportal.com/scss-to-css/)